t.test in R cannot use formula method when using 'paired' = TRUE
I like the logic of formula notation in R. This also works with the t.test. However, when performing a paired t.test the formula function in R version 4.4.1 is not allowed. Students with older installations are able to use formula notation. What is going on?
response <- c(5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 9, 6, 8)
group <- factor(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B"))

t.test(response ~ group, paired = TRUE) # this won't work in my R verion?


Error in t.test.formula(response ~ group, paired = TRUE) :
cannot use 'paired' in formula method
Is there some package interference? Why did it work in the past but now stopped working?

This is because "If paired is TRUE then both x and y must be specified and they must be the same length." The formula doesn't guarantee that the groups are of the same length, not even that there are only two groups. That's why t.test needs the vectors explicitly.

When running paired tests, you need to know which A value goes with which B value. If you assign them differently, you get different results. It's hard to specify that level of matching with the formula. The change was made in R 4.4.0.

Thanks this answered my question. Maybe you can post it as an official answer?
